# How can I shift table cells and make an image appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

When the user presses the "Download" button, I want all the cells in the table to shift to the right side, and correspondingly an image be displayed on the left side.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: are you putting the image inside or outside the tableview?

Comment: inside as i want to show a user that when user press a button all images he can see and on particular cell selection image will be replace in short  i want to implement a multiple row selection and then download files

Comment: Then, please check my answer. I bet it's what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fastest way is changing the way the data source behaves for your table. When you build the table you do it in the common way. When you click on the button, you update the data source flagging a boolean variable into it to the `YES` value, then in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, if `flag == YES` you can add a image to the cell.

If you rely on the standard cells, you can try this:

```
if (flag) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
} else {
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

And at the end of the click event you should reload the table:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

It's a quick and dirt solution, but should work fine.

Comment: should i call tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: metod in my butoon click event method and then reload table or just set flag==YES and if-else in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and [tableview reloadData]; in click event

Comment: The latter one is the solution. In the click event you update the flag and reload data. And you will have to change the data source methods as explained in the answer.

Comment: thank you so much its working perfectly, as what i needed, now just have to change image on selection and then download files ya but i hope i will do it thanks